# Restricting Memory Game to Only Allow Two Cards Open at Once in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, logic, game-development

I'm creating a simple memory game in react and have a problem where it is possible to select more than two cards at once. The game works as it should when only clicking two cards, but breaks if you select more.

I have tried to limit the amount of cards in openCards to 2 before flipping another, but it didn't work. I have also considered adding all cards that are not open to disabledCards when you've selected two, but that would mix them up with the cards that are already a match.

```
function App() {
  const [images, setImages] = useState([]);
  const [openCards, setOpenCards] = useState([]);
  const [shouldFlipBack, setShouldFlipBack] = useState(false);
  const [disabledCards, setDisabledCards] = useState([]);  //cards that are matched
  const imageArray = [
    {type: "penguin", image: penguin},
    {type: "penguin", image: penguin},
    {type: "snail", image: snail},
    {type: "snail", image: snail},
    {type: "chicken", image: chicken},
    {type: "chicken", image: chicken},
    {type: "raccoon", image: raccoon},
    {type: "raccoon", image: raccoon},
    {type: "fox", image: fox},
    {type: "fox", image: fox}
  ];

  useEffect(() => {
    setImages((prevImages) => shuffleImages(prevImages));
  }, []);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    if (openCards.length === 2) {
      checkIfMatch();
      setOpenCards([]);
    }
  }, [openCards]);

  function checkIfMatch() {  
    if (openCards[0] === openCards[1]) {
      console.log("match");
      setDisabledCards(()=> [...disabledCards, openCards[0]]);
      setShouldFlipBack(false);

    } else {
        console.log("not match");
        setTimeout(() => {
          setShouldFlipBack(true);
        }, 1000); 
    }
    setShouldFlipBack(false);
  }
```

```
function Card({card, setOpenCards, openCards, shouldFlipBack, disabledCards}) {
  const [isFlipped, setFlipped] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!disabledCards.includes(card.type)) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        setFlipped(false);
      }, 500);
    }
  }, [shouldFlipBack]);

  function flipCard() {
    if (!disabledCards.includes(card.type)) {
      setFlipped(!isFlipped);
      setOpenCards(()=> [...openCards, card.type]);
    }
  }
  return (
    <div className="card" onClick={flipCard}>
      <div className={isFlipped ? "card-inner flipped" : "card-inner"}>
        <div className="card-front"></div>
        <div className="card-back">
          {isFlipped && <img src={card.image} alt="card" />}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Card;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do one of two things:

1. Move the click handler up so it's in the parent component
2. pass a prop into the card that says if it's allowed to flip or not.

I think the first gives a better design, so that's what I will show:

```
const noop = () => {}

function App() {
  const [images, setImages] = useState([]);
  const [shouldFlipBack, setShouldFlipBack] = useState(false);
  const [isPending, setIsPEnding] = useState(false);
  
  const imageArray = [
    {type: "penguin", image: penguin, isFlipped: false, isMatcced: false},
    {type: "penguin", image: penguin, isFlipped: false, isMatched: false},
    {type: "snail", image: snail, isFlipped: false, isMatched: false},
    {type: "snail", image: snail, isFlipped: false, isMatched: false},
    {type: "chicken", image: chicken, isFlipped: false, isMatched: false},
    {type: "chicken", image: chicken, isFlipped: false, isMatched: false},
    {type: "raccoon", image: raccoon}, isFlipped: false, isMatched: false,
    {type: "raccoon", image: raccoon, isFlipped: false, isMatched: false},
    {type: "fox", image: fox, isFlipped: false, isMatcched: false},
    {type: "fox", image: fox, isFlipped: false, isMatcched: false}
  ];

  const flippedButNotMatched = useMemo(images => image.isFlippedlipped && !image.isMatched, [images]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setImages(shuffleImages(imageArray));
  }, []);

  const flipCard = useCallback(cardIndex => {
     const card = images[cardIndex]
     setImages(prevImages => image === card ? {...card, isFlipped: true} : image)
     if (flippedButNotMatched.length == 1 && flippedButNotMatched[0].type === card.type) {
        return;
     }
     setIsPending(true);
     const cancel = setTimeout(() => {
        setIsPending(true)
        setImages(prevImages => image.isMatched ? image : {...image, isFlipped: false})
     }, 500) 
     return () => clearTimeout(cancel)
  }, [flippedButNotMatched]}

  return (<div>
     {images.map((image, i) => 
        <Card isFlipped={image.isFlipped} onClick={pending||image.isMapped ? noop: () => flipCard(i) />
     )}
  </div>)
}
```

Good luck!